# Trailing zeros vs rounding in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I want to typeset U=220kV and C=12,8nF. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  exponent-mode = engineering,
  prefix-mode = combine-exponent
}
\begin{document}
 $U=\qty{220000}{\V}$ ,
 $C=\qty{0,0000000128}{\F}$
\end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image]

C=12,8nF is fine, but U=220,000kV has unwanted trailing zeros. Addition of siunitx-option `round-pad=false` has no effect on these zeros.

Similar with additional option `round-mode = places`, only the amount of trailing zeros depends on the choice of `round-precision`.

Use of `round-mode = figures` instead yields:[image]

Now U=220kV is fine, but C has unwantedly been rounded to C=13nF. Because of a default `round-precision=2` ?

After a further addition of the option `round-precision=3` finally everything is fine. But only in this example.

I don't know the amount of significant figures or places in advance, so I would prefer a more general mechanism to avoid both unwanted trailing zeros or unwanted rounding. How could this work?

Comment: How do you expect `siunitx` to know when rounding is desired and when it is unwanted? In your example, you provide one value with 6 significant figures and one with 3 and want both of them to be printed with 3 significant figures. This can be easily done, as you found yourself. But then you say that you don't know the amount of significant figures or places in advance, so how would `siunitx` know?

Comment: Also, the obvious question: Why not just type `\qty{220}{\kilo\volt}` and `\qty{12.8}{\nano\farad}`? Or even `\qty{220e3}{\volt}` and `\qty{12.8e-9}{\farad}`?

Comment: In my real application the values are calculated externally and stored in a .csv as shown here without any exponents. `datatool` picks them from there. So I don't know in advance if I need a `\kilo` or `\nano` or whatever and want to leave that job for `siunitx`.

Comment: Yes, "220000" has six significant figures. Counting from the right end the engineering notation replaces zeros in portions of three by `kilo`, `mega` and so on. In my understanding this is a mere notation convention and no rounding at all.  I would expect it to be part of the `prefix-mode=combine-exponent` option rather than part of `round-mode = figures` . For me it is non-intuitive that this notation thing is mixed with some rounding, as it appears with the capacity value of my example.

Comment: The prefixes `kilo` etc. do _not_ replace zeros, they just shift the decimal marker. Changing the number of significant figures means changing the value. A measurement of `10 MV` is very different from a measurement of `10.000000 MV`.

Comment: I don't know `datatool`, so I don't know if it provides any useful functionality here. I think the right point of attack here is the external preparation of the values, i.e. you should store them in the `csv` file with the right amount of significant figures (in scientific notation). After all, `siunitx` is for _typesetting_ numbers, not for numerical evaluations.